# How to make an image static when scrolling

Tags: html, background, border, fixed

So I have a border at the top of the page and I want it to stay in the same spot when I scroll down. I've tried putting `position: fixed` in many different spots and still can't make it work.  Also, I would like the other content to scroll behind this image if possible. This is my code:

```
    <div style='
      background-image: url(http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/bowlace2.gif);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;'>
         <img src="http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/bowlace2.gif">
    </div>
```

it's for the page nikkidarlinggg.tumblr.com
sorry If I'm not typing this correctly, I've never used this site before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these styles to the div:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, how would I create a space underneath the border so it's not touching the images when first visiting the page? I know it will overlap after I start scrolling. Could I use something like: padding-bottom:10px; ?

Comment: To add some spacing above the images, add the following style to the div with id="cage": `padding-top: 55px`

Comment: I don't really know much about code, where exactly would I put that? And will the sidebar with my text move down as well? Because I would like it to be lower also.

Comment: You could replace <div id="cage"> with <div id="cage" style="padding-top:55px;">

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem :

```
   <div  class='fixed' ></div>
   <div class='content'>Your content here </div>
```

and fixed class :

```
.fixed{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 z-index: 1;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-image:url(http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/bowlace2.gif);background-     
 repeat: repeat-x; 
}
.content{margin-top:57px;}
```

using css inside css inside your html :

```
   <div style="position:fixed; top:0; z-index: 1; width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/bowlace2.gif);background-repeat: repeat-x;" >
  </div>
  <div style='margin-top:57px;'>Your content here </div>
```

DEMO HERE : http://jsfiddle.net/Nsuj7/

Comment: This fiddle is not working. Can you please update?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `position:absolute` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/bowlace2.gif);background-repeat: repeat-x;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:2;height:57px"></div>
```

Try this, using z-index 2 or any above value.